# What type to use in Java for column with enum in Postgres?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am having the following schema in PostgreSQL

```
student_master(
    enroll_id varchar(6),
    name varchar(25),
    class class_enum
)
```

Here, class_enum is enum created with

```
create type class_enum as enum('1','2','3')
```

Now, I am creating a model class in Java to connect to the database using hibernate.
Initially, I declared a "class" column with character data type but I got following exception

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "class" is of type class_enum but expression is of type character varying`

What type should I use to match this variable in Java class with the PostgreSQL column type?

Comment: Create enum in Java also.
https://vladmihalcea.com/map-postgresql-enum-array-jpa-entity-property-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to provide enum also on Java side, and let hibernate know how to convert between db value and java.

See [The best way to map an Enum Type with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-an-enum-type-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

> To map this PostgreSQL type we can no longer use the default Hibernate-specific org.hibernate.type.EnumType because PostgreSQL expects an Object type, not a VARCHAR or an INT.
>
> Luckily, we can easily create a custom Type by extending org.hibernate.type.EnumType

```
public class PostgreSQLEnumType extends org.hibernate.type.EnumType {
 
    public void nullSafeSet(
            PreparedStatement st,
            Object value,
            int index,
            SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        st.setObject(
            index,
            value != null ?
                ((Enum) value).name() :
                null,
            Types.OTHER
        );
    }
}
```

In your case, as the values (1, 2, 3) are not valid enum identifiers, you can add a private field in your enum and use that instead of `name()`

Answer (score 0):

Add this property to my application.properties file fixed the issue for me:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.stringtype=unspecified
```